# Stop Scrapy from converting "—" to "&mdash;" from URL

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding, scrapy, middleware

One of the websites that I am working on, frequently uses `—` in URL and Scrapy converts it in to `&mdash;` before processing; I am trying to modify it back to `—` through adding few lines in default Download Middleware and it does print everything fine however Scrapy converts it back again, which eventually results as 404.

```
'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES' : {
    'something.middlewares.MyDownloaderMiddleware': 540
}
```

middlewares.py

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
from html import escape, unescape

class MyDownloaderMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        new_url = unescape(unquote(request.url))
        print (new_url)
        request = request.replace(url=new_url)
        return None
```

I tried `return request` instead of `return none` in the middleware, however still it doesn't seem to work either.

Solution:

I have placed couple of `.replace("&mdash;", "—")` in spider code, it's working now though my first approach was to do it via middleware, which should have been a cleaner approach.

Comment: “Scrapy converts it in to &mdash; before processing”. Requests to URLs are yielded from your spiders, not from Scrapy. Where in Scrapy does a URL get `&mdash;`? Can you provide a reproducible example? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: visit "https://www.ecstuning.com/b-ecs-parts/c-novelty_-and-_gifts-mini-apparel-shirts/" and then click "Short Sleeve T-Shirts" under Categories, this is a sample link - even if I copy paste it here, browser modifies it to &mdash; therefore try it yourself.